# Android app without instalation?

Tags: android

Last time I've heard about running android app without installing it.
Like "demo app" or something like that.
What doest it mean?
Generally you have to go to Google Play in order to install the app and run it.
It isn't via a browser, because you can supposedly use the android app functions

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Comment: "sth" man just type out the word

Comment: sorry - corrected

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's Instant App.

Here you have [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Instant Apps are the next step in app evolution, a universal Android solution that brings the speed and power of a native app with the ease and immediacy of a web app. They look and operate just like one of the apps that are installed on your phone, but you don’t need to download anything.
Android Instant Apps allow you to use native Android apps in a form that doesn’t even require installing. Which means the users get to experience interactive and smooth interfaces with the tap of a finger.

**Note:** Android Instant Apps only work on Android devices running on Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher.

For further info about instant apps you can refer to following link

https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/overview.html#apps-features

Answer (score 2):

An instant app is a portion of your app that will be executed in response to an Url. This was introduced by Google year.

Google play store will download the code necessary to execute the task it is supposed to and it will dispose of the code after the user is done.

You would create an Instant apps if you mean to provide specific feature of your app that does not require the user to download the full app. Ex: watch a video on vimeo by clicking a link on social media

This apps are built using the same process you would use to develop a regular android app but instead of developing all of the features in the same module you divide the features in different modules. 
This modules should be very small and have a size limit of 4MB.

Instant apps are currently limited to a few countries, so if you are thinking of developing one and putting in production check the link below for this information and others documents on how to get started.

https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/overview.html